# Вывести родительские страницы wordpress

Tags: wordpress

всем привет.
Нужно вывести дочерние страницы из 3-х родительских.
Выглядит это так: заголовки 3-х родительских страниц и под ними все ихние дочерние страницы.

Есть такой код: выводится не так как надо.

```
<?php global $post;

        $args_parent = array(
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'include' => array(20,37,23),
            'posts_per_page' => 3
        );
        $query = get_posts( $args_parent );

        foreach($query as $product) { ?>
            <div class="production-item">
                <?php
                $children = array(
                    'post_type' => 'page',
                    'child_of' => $product->ID,
                );
                $child = new WP_Query( $children ); ?>
                <div class="production-item-title"><?php echo $product->post_title; ?></div>
                <ul class="production-item-list">
                    <?php if ( $child->have_posts() ) {
                    while ( $child->have_posts() ) {
                    $child->the_post(); ?>
                    <li><?php the_title(); ?></li>
                    <?php } } wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <?php }
        ?>
```

Выводятся одинаковые дочерние
[image: скриншот]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо параметра `child_of` используйте `post_parent__in`

Другими словами:

```
<?php
$children = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_parent__in' => array($product->ID),
);
?>
```

Подробнее про параметры запроса читайте в [справке](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#post-page-parameters).

Comment: Спасибо, целый день мучался.